# How create objects with position data(x,y,z) in Unity3D using data from a json file?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

So I have a JSON file like this,

"TestFile.json" →

```
[
   {"OBJECT_ID": "1960", 
   "OBJECT_NAME": "CHARLIE 1 DEB", 
   "X_COORDINATE": "47.2145", 
   "Y_COORDINATE": "1682.976", 
   "Z_COORDINATE": "1517.269", 
   "SPEED":"20.25",
   "OWNER": "MICHAEL FARADAY"
},
   {"OBJECT_ID": "1960_1", 
   "OBJECT_NAME": "CHARLIE 1 DEB_2", 
   "X_COORDINATE": "41.2145", 
   "Y_COORDINATE": "1682.976", 
   "Z_COORDINATE": "417.269", 
   "SPEED":"14.15",
   "OWNER": "MICHAEL FARADAY"
},
   {"OBJECT_ID": "1960_2", 
   "OBJECT_NAME": "CHARLIE 1 DEB_2", 
   "X_COORDINATE": "49.541", 
   "Y_COORDINATE": "1232.886", 
   "Z_COORDINATE": "1520.600", 
   "SPEED":"37.19",
   "OWNER": "MICHAEL FARADAY"
}
]
```

Now I want to create three objects using this json file in unity 3D. (Or more objects according to the given json data)

What is the best way to do this? Suggesting documentary will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has `JsonUtility`. You have to use [JsonUtility.FromJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)

Also, look how it can be used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity).

You should create a class which contains these 7 fields and then deserialize the json into array or list. Then just take x,y,z fields’ values to set objects’ position.